# Поставить защиту php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с автомобилями, где у каждого автомобиля есть `ID`.  Как мне поставить защиту, если в таблице нет такого автомобиля вернуть `false` иначе `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пример:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM auto WHERE id = '1' ") or die ("Error #6754632"); // проверим есть ли в бд 
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
    // TRUE
} else {
    // FALSE
}
```

Comment: тут точно все правильно?

Comment: просто сделайте у себя условие и внутри вызовите функцию, котороя принимает переменную с sql запросом

Answer (score -1):

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: вы не забыли `WHERE` случайно?

Comment: зато я не забыл

Comment: блин у меня не получается

Comment: можно код скину разберетес